# Return office details from multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

The function itself is just returning as `void`. But, the point of the posted code is not about what the function is returning. It is the code related to using T-SQL and C# to return data from a SQL database that I would like reviewed. Especially the way the `using` statements are structured.

```
    public void GetOffice(int syncID)
    {
        string strQry = @"
Select so.SyncID, 
   so.title
From Offices o
Left Outer Join SyncOffices so On so.id = o.SyncID
Where o.SyncID = @syncID
"; 

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Settings.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(strQry, conn))
            {
                objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@syncID", syncID);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = objCommand.ExecuteReader();

                if (rdr.Read())
                {
                    this.OfficeName= rdr.GetString(1);
                }

                rdr.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, kudos for using a `Parameter` and not concatenating the value into your T-SQL string.

You're not disposing all `IDisposable` objects. `SqlDataReader` should be disposed as well. Now this makes it quite a bunch of nested `using` scopes, which you could rework like this:

```
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Settings.ConnectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@syncID", syncId);
        connection.Open();

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                this.OfficeName = reader.GetString(1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Note:

- Usage of `var` for implicit typing makes the code easier to read (IMO), if you're using C# 3.0+
- Disemvoweling is bad. There's no reason to call a variable `rdr` over `reader`. Use meaningful names, always.
- Hungarian notation is evil. There's no reason to prefix a `string` with `str`.
- Stick to camelCasing for locals - that includes parameters, so `syncID` becomes `syncId`.

The code assumes the query only returns 1 row, but the query isn't written to explicitly select a single row. This could lead to unexpected results.

Given some `IList<string> results = new List<string>();`:

```
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                results.Add(reader.GetString(1));
            }
        }
```

You could then do `this.OfficeName = results.Single();` (which would blow up if no rows were returned). One thing that strikes me, is that you're selecting 2 fields, but only using 1, which makes this `reader.GetString(1)` statement look surprising. If you don't need to select the `SyncID` field, remove it from your query and do `reader.GetString(0)` instead.

Finally, the T-SQL itself:

```
Select so.SyncID, so.title
From Offices o
Left Outer Join SyncOffices so On so.id = o.SyncID
Where o.SyncID = @syncID
```

Could look like this:

```
SELECT so.Title
FROM Offices o
LEFT JOIN SyncOffices so ON so.id = o.SyncID
WHERE o.SyncID = @syncID
```

Or, in a string:

```
var sql = "SELECT so.Title FROM Offices o LEFT JOIN SyncOffices so ON so.Id = o.SyncId WHERE o.SyncId = @syncId";
```

The line breaks make it look weird, and since it's not too long of a query, I think it would make the code better to have it on a single line.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Everything makes sense. I want to point out that I am only expecting 1 row.

Comment: If you're going to use `FirstOrDefault()` then I don't see any reason to retrieve the extra rows. (It would be different if you used `SingleOrDefault()` or `Single()`, which I usually prefer.)

Comment: Also, if you make the string into a single-line, you can drop the `@` before the `"`.

Answer (score 2):

I notice that `GetOffice` returns `void` and that the result of the query is written into `this.OfficeName`.

I usually have one (separate) file which contains/encapsulates all my SQL statements. So I'd have something like,

```
public void GetOffice(int syncID)
{
    this.OfficeName = Sql.GetOfficeName(syncID);
}
```

... where `GetOfficeName` is a static method of my `Sql` class.

Having all my SQL in one (separate file) makes it easier to do a code review of all the ways in which I use SQL; for example to ensure that I'm using the same 'best practices' (e.g. using transactions, disposing objects) in all SQL-related methods.